# Find the radius of convergence given a recurrence relation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, power-series

I have the following recurrence relation for the coefficients $c_n$ of the power series: $y = \sum^\infty_{n=0}c_nx^n$

$$c_{n+1} = \frac{n+2}{5(n+1)}c_n$$

What is the radius of convergence of the power series?

I can find the radius of convergence by finding  a formula for $c_n$ and then find the limit of $|\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}|$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

Is there a way to determine its radius of convergence without finding the formula first?

Comment: Wait... you know that $$\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}=5\frac{n+1}{n+2}$$ hence finding the limit $$\lim\left|\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}\right|$$ should not be too computationally costly, should it? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get $$\frac{5^{n+1}}{n+2}c_{n+1}=\frac{5^n}{n+1}c_n=…=c_0$$ so that you can get the explicit form of the power series, and from that read directly off its radius of convergence.

---

You can of course also directly evaluate the quotient expression $$\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}=\frac{5(n+1)}{n+2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

This may be a sledgehammer for your problem but there is a general theorem.

> **Poincare theorem**$\color{blue}{{}^{[1]}}$
>
> Given any recurrence relations with non-constant coefficients
>   $$x_{n+k} + p_1(n)x_{n+k-1} + p_2(n)x_{n+k-2} + \cdots + p_k(n) x_{n} = 0\tag{*1}$$
>   such that there are real numbers $p_i, 1 \le i \le k$ with
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} p_i(n) = p_i, \quad 1 \le i \le k$$
>   and the roots $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \ldots, \lambda_k$ for the associated characteristic equation:
>   $$\lambda^k + p_1 \lambda^{k-1} + \cdots + p_k = 0$$
>   have distinct moduli.
>
> For any solution of $(*1)$, either $x_n = 0$ for all large $n$ 
>   or $\displaystyle\;\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \lambda_i\;$ for some $i$.

In short, if the coefficients of a recurrence relations converges and the corresponds $|\lambda_i|$ are distinct, then either the sequence $x_n$ terminates (i.e. infinite radius of convergence) or the radius of convergence is one of $\frac{1}{|\lambda_i|}$.

For your case, it is clear $c_n$ didn't terminate. Since the characteristic equation of your sequence "converge" to $\lambda - \frac15$, its radius of convergence is $5$.

**Notes/References**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - Saber Elaydi, An Introduction to difference equations, $\S 8.2$ Poincare theorem.